# how to set theme to a particular item

Tags: android

I want to set halo theme. A number picker and an activity on which it is presented have different themes. I have done this in the xml property and given the number picker the halo theme. But it is not working. Please help....

my....
style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Animations" />

    <style name="Animations.GrowFromBottom">
        <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/grow_from_bottom</item>
        <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/shrink_from_top</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Animations.GrowFromTop">
        <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/grow_from_top</item>
        <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/shrink_from_bottom</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Animations.PopDownMenu">
        <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/grow_from_topleft_to_bottomright</item>
        <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/shrink_from_bottomright_to_topleft</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AndroDev" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></style>

</resources>
```

my manifest file....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tablet"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SonyTabletActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my xml....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
        style="@style/AndroDev"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should add your code to help other people to help you. I think in your case these are xml files.

Answer (score 0):

### For Activity

---

- To do it from manifest file: append `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` in your activity tag
- To do it in Activity class, you can do it by `super.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme.Holo.Light)`

### For number picker

---

Create a custom style by res/values/style.xml.

```
<?xml version.....>
<resources>
<style name="AndroDev" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Then use this in xml where your number picker view is defined:

```
<NumberPickerView style:"@style/AndroDev" ....>
```

I have taken example of Holo.Light theme. You can change to whatever you want.

Comment: in manifest i have android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" and i have done the same as you suggested for the numberpicker but it is not helping...please tell what to do.

Comment: Have you a created new style in style.xml and applied in your number picker?

Comment: yes i have made the new style as mentioned by you and applied it to the numberpicker...

Comment: I have edited my theme style. Just use that. Also remove android:background attribute from your xml.

Comment: I have done the same but number picker is still not change according to holo theme.Is there problem in my manifest file since i have used @android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar  theme for that activity.

Comment: Got the same issue for NumberPicker. It seems that this widget can not be customized which is a shame. The only thing that can be changed is the background. I am dead ... if anyone has a solution for this then please let us know. Good luck